# Perl data in new line cannot be extracted

Tags: perl, hash, file-io

I have a large set of data which is coming from executing some commands and I am extracting some part from those data which are needed for my further processing. As of now I am storing this in a hash `%data_hash`.

Here is my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my %data_hash;
my @data = <DATA> ;

foreach my $data_line ( @data ){
    chomp $data_line;
    if( $data_line =~ m/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}\;[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}/){
        my ($primary,$date,$time,$priority,$obj,$id,$text) = split(";", $data_line);

        $data_hash{$primary}{$id}{'DateTime'}   = $date." ".$time;
        $data_hash{$primary}{$id}{'priority'}   = $priority;
        $data_hash{$primary}{$id}{'obj'}        = $obj;
        $data_hash{$primary}{$id}{'text'}       = $text;
    }
}

print Dumper(\%data_hash);

__DATA__
.......
.......
Pr1: Date;Time;Priority;Object;ID;OtherInfo
Pr1: 2019-11-21;15:30:54;Low;Obj1;1;No Info Provided
.......
.......
Pr2: Date;Time;Priority;Object;ID;OtherInfo
Pr2: 2019-11-22;10:30:00;High;Obj2;2;Line Missing
Pr2: 2019-11-20;11:01:01;Low;Obj3 is example obj;
 5;No Info Provided
Pr2: 2019-11-20;05:10:10;High;Obj9;4;Line Missing
.......
.......
```

and the resulting `hash` for the above input file is:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'Pr1' => {
                    '1' => {
                             'priority' => 'Low',
                             'text' => 'No Info Provided',
                             'obj' => 'Obj1',
                             'DateTime' => '2019-11-21 15:30:54'
                           }
                  },
          'Pr2' => {
                    '2' => {
                             'obj' => 'Obj2',
                             'DateTime' => '2019-11-22 10:30:00',
                             'text' => 'Line Missing',
                             'priority' => 'High'
                           },
                    '' => {
                            'text' => undef,
                            'priority' => 'Low',
                            'obj' => 'Obj3 is example obj',
                            'DateTime' => '2019-11-20 11:01:01'
                          },
                    '4' => {
                             'obj' => 'Obj9',
                             'DateTime' => '2019-11-20 05:10:10',
                             'text' => 'Line Missing',
                             'priority' => 'High'
                           }
                  }
        };
```

If you see the hash dumper, for `Pr2` one of the key is set to `undef` since the data(`ID`) in input file is kept in new line(which is actually a continuation of previous line`5;No Info Provided`)

How can I take this `ID` as one of the key for `Pr2` while reading an input file.

Comment: How do you know that the data on a line continues on the next line? For example, will there always be a continuation line if the number of fields on a line is less than 7?

Comment: @HåkonHægland yes. For all the data there should be a 7 fields.

Comment: Ok, also would it be possible to have more than one data line on a file line, e.g a line with 14 fields could define two data lines, or a line with 8 fields could define the 4 last items on one line and the 4 first on the next data line?

Comment: @HåkonHægland No. At the maximum there should be only 7 fields in single data line.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

```
my %data_hash;
my $data = do { local $/; <DATA> };
while ($data =~ /
                (\S+):\s([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2});
                ([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2});
                ([^;]+);
                ([^;]+);
                ([^;]+);
                ([^;\n]+) /gx){
    my ($primary,$date,$time,$priority,$obj,$id,$text) 
      =  map { s/^\s+|\s+$//gr } @{^CAPTURE};
    $data_hash{$primary}{$id}{'DateTime'}   = $date." ".$time;
    $data_hash{$primary}{$id}{'priority'}   = $priority;
    $data_hash{$primary}{$id}{'obj'}        = $obj;
    $data_hash{$primary}{$id}{'text'}       = $text;        
}
```

**Output**:

```
$VAR1 = {
      'Pr1' => {
                 '1' => {
                          'DateTime' => '2019-11-21 15:30:54',
                          'text' => 'No Info Provided',
                          'obj' => 'Obj1',
                          'priority' => 'Low'
                        }
               },
      'Pr2' => {
                 '5' => {
                          'DateTime' => '2019-11-20 11:01:01',
                          'obj' => 'Obj3 is example obj',
                          'text' => 'No Info Provided',
                          'priority' => 'Low'
                        },
                 '4' => {
                          'obj' => 'Obj9',
                          'text' => 'Line Missing',
                          'DateTime' => '2019-11-20 05:10:10',
                          'priority' => 'High'
                        },
                 '2' => {
                          'priority' => 'High',
                          'obj' => 'Obj2',
                          'text' => 'Line Missing',
                          'DateTime' => '2019-11-22 10:30:00'
                        }
               }
    };
```

Comment: I have updated the question (Input file in DATA handler). The format is slight different. And yes, there is maximum of 7 fields in each data line.

Comment: Now there is a colon in the first field: `Pr1:Date`. Is that a typo? It should be a semicolon, right?

Comment: Its not typo. ```Pr1:Date``` or ```Pr1:2019-11-21``` is the actual data.

Comment: Ok, then there is only 6 fields per line?

Comment: Exactly. And that looks like ```Pr1: Date;Time;Priority;Object;ID;OtherInfo```. There is a space between ```Pr1:``` and ```Date```.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply read and append lines until you have seven ";"

```
my $data_line= '';
foreach my $line ( @data ){
    chomp $line;
    $data_line.= $line;
    my ($primary,$date,$time,$priority,$obj,$id,$text) = split(";", $data_line);
    next unless defined $text;
    # your stuff here
    $data_line= '';
}
```